# How do I manipulate the stock market?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

With the addition of the various stock exchanges across the galaxy, its now possible to buy shares in companies and futures in commodities.  Do my actions in any of the stock exchange areas affect any other areas in the galaxy?  For example, if I were to buy all futures for entertainment chips in stock exchange zone, will it affect the prices of entertainment chips in neighboring zones?

Are the corporation stock prices affected by anything in the game?  If their trading ships were to mysteriously disappear, will it drive down their stock?

Finally, can I collapse the universe economy?  If I were to buy all available futures in energy cells, can I create a galactic wide energy depression until everyone's forced to purchase from me and I can charge them an outrageous price?

Comment: "[C]an I collapse the universe economy"?  Remind me never to play a strategy game against you!

Comment: you probably need to destroy the factories and plants too

Answer (score 9):

Corporation stocks are determined by the value of all of their combined assets, so if you pirated, say, OTAS ships all to hell, then yes, their stock prices would go down.

Company stocks shift randomly, it seems. Nothing affects them externally.

Futures in items like weapons or food are determined by supply and demand, so if you bought up all the meatsteaks in existence, you'd drive stock prices to extremes. Alternately, if you suddenly flooded the market with meatsteaks, prices on their stock would plummet.

Futures in Natural items also appear to shift randomly.

So yes, you can manipulate the market, but only by actually removing or bolstering supply, or in the case of corporations, assets in any form, be it ships, goods, or stations.

Comment: Hi Tim, great answer!  Do you know if the naturals in the stock exchanges are all linked or are they each individual to those sectors and uninfluenced by anything else?

Answer (score 3):

I filled a Mammoth with 8200ish units of Nividium (Mined in Guiding Star), jumped into PTNI Headquarters, bought all the shares for Nividium (cost around 130Mil), jumped to Nyanas Hideout, and sold for about 500 mil.
Remember to keep a ship or sat in PTNI so you can remote trade.

I started with a TS filled with 700ish units of Nividium until I could afford more mining ships and the Mammoth. Stopped long enough to mine out the Nividium in Guiding Star and then went to town on the Profitssss.

Comment: I mined 2500 units manualy by ramming asteroids with Terran TL :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't affect the price of the futures of a commodity by purchasing all of the futures.  However, you can affect the price of the future by buying all of the physical inventory.  The cycles of the future prices are strongly tied to supply and demand.  If you can clear out the supply of a commodity, the price (and the future) will go up as well.

Note, this is strongly linked to the demand for the commodity.  We've all seen energy cell prices shoot up when the inventory drops because the demand is so high.  Don't expect to see a similar effect if you buy up all the sunrise flowers in an Argon sector.

So, no, trading in the futures market won't collapse the economy.  Buying all the physical energy cells would, however, have a dramatic effect on the galaxy (and you're cargo capacity).

Answer (score 1):

Before recent patch, you could eg. be in ship which carried nvidium and be in PTNI HQ. sector and price of it would drop (index 200) in local exchange. And when you transported to other ship, price would raise.

Don't know whether they fixed this exploit (in patch notes were only that they fixed some).

Answer (score 1):

Exploit:

I bought all the satellite shares in Grand Exchange, then bought up all of the satellites. The supply was still the same, so I left the sectors of this stock market with the goods in my cargo, and supply went to 0. That done, I sold the shares and made about 250k profit. I crossed the gate back to a sector covered by this stock market, supply went back up and I bought the shares again...

That would expose mechanics for tradeable goods.

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing with ore, I have 3 mammoths filled with ore, I jump then into a sector the trading price goes to 50cr then jump them out and sell around 180cr. I think the most I have made is 8,000,000 in 1 trade. Light of heart stock exchange is best for ore. Im now working on getting another 2 mammoths filled with ore so I can manipulate the price in argon prime. Ill make mega bucks!!

Comment: use Space Fuel, with 1 Mammonth it will be aroun 50 Millions